# Fantasy book trilogy with VR game. Protagonist is a bard

Tags: story-identification

Years ago I read a fantasy trilogy, which I’ve since loaned to someone and never got back.

It was about a man who was developing a VR game which was entered via a sensory deprivation tank. Something happened and he got stuck in the game, where if you died you would also die in real life. It was a fantasy medieval kind of a game, where he was playing a bard.

In real life he had a wife and they were really good fencers. They’ve crashed a plane in France and he ended up having trouble with his leg and she ended up only as organs held together in a plastic case. At the end he sort of became his wife in game and had a child and I think she was evil(?)

Comment: Can't you ask the person the you loaned it to?

Comment: Unfortunately not, we had a bit of a falling out.

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

It's called [***In the Net of Dreams***](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/813484.In_the_Net_of_Dreams) by Wm. Mark Simmons.

> Dreamland. A complex world of computer-generated dream games.
>   Dreamwalkers can exchange their bodies for avatars - dream bodies that
>   they can choose for themselves - and adventure in dozens of different
>   virtual realities. There is no real pain, no real danger...until the
>   program develops a deadly glitch!
>
> Now the Fantasyworld program has locked-up and hundreds of gamers and
>   dreamwalkers are trapped in a virtual environment populated with elves
>   and dragons and all sorts of medieval and magical menace. Instead of
>   waking up when their avatars are killed, dreamwalkers are experiencing
>   terminal feedback and are actually dying inside their life-support
>   modules!
>
> Cephtronics must now convince the man who wrote the books the
>   Programworld is based on--the man they fired and sued five years
>   earlier--to risk his own life and sanity. Robert R Ripley must find a
>   back door to his stolen virtual world, sneak inside, find the source
>   of the anomaly, and unlock the matrix before everyone in-system dies
>   in two worlds.

[image: Cover of "In the Net of Dreams", showing a white horse with purple wings. It has the text "Come play the game: magic is the way, heroes are the means, and reality is but a dream. Or is it?"]

Comment: +1 for a self-answer, but don't forget to include some info about how the book matches your description. I find that adding the blurb usually suffices

Comment: And this will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90492/full-body-vr-sim-where-characters-are-trapped-in-a-fantasy-world/218179?r=SearchResults#218179

Comment: You will be able to self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons in about 43 hours (there's a two day moratorium for self-answers).